# sender-host=ARG - Nagios

Tags: powershell, nagios, nagiosxi

I’m currently working on Windows Server 2016 with NSClient++ (x64) 0.5.0062

I have written a powershell script to send notifications to Nagios using this line of code

```
Set-Alias nscp "C:\Program Files\NSClient++\nscp.exe" -Scope Global

nscp client --module NSCAClient address=172.22.50.9:5667 encryption=XOR command="MDI_zip_d" result=$status message="$global:statusInformation"
```

I have set the nsclient.ini on the section [/settings/NSCA/client] a new hostname, you see… My current hostname on the server is all capitalized like this, MDIARCH03, the server on Nagios is configured in lowercase letter… Before this version of Nagios, I used to tell through the above command the server name through the line sender-host=mdiarch03 and that would work just fine. But ever since we upgraded to this new version the passive check won’t work.

This is what I get from the event log

[09-03-2018 17:26:12] Error: External command failed -> PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT;MDIARCH03;MDI_zip_d;2;teste do nagios [09-03-2018 17:26:11] Warning: Passive check result was received for service ‘MDI_zip_d’ on host ‘MDIARCH03’, but the host could not be found!

Comment: Do you have host configured called MDIARCH03 (think that is case sensitive) configured in Nagios?

Comment: @Matt Yes, I do... the windows hostname is set as MDIARCH03, but the host set on Nagios is mdiarch03.